# Screen cast out of sync with audio

Tags: 14.04, avconv

I have been trying to record my screen for some YouTube videos I make but on Ubuntu whenever I run the command `avconv -s 1600x900 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 -f pulse -i default -c:a aac sample.mp4` the audio falls out of sync. I have figured out that the video is what advances and delays. What can I do to make sure that the audio and video stay in sync when I record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across this problem once. I've solved the problem by using:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec alac -ab 128k -f x11grab -s `xdpyinfo | grep dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -r 25 -i :0.0 -sameq final.mkv
```

I've explained the details of this command in a blog post [here](http://ephemeral.me/blog/2013/05/07/screencasting-in-ubuntu-ultimate-solution/).